# How to remove a downstream or upstream task dependency in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

Assuming we have the two following Airflow tasks in a DAG,

```
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_1')
t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_2')
```

we can specify dependencies as:

```
# Option A
t1 >> t2

# Option B
t2.set_upstream(t1)

# Option C
t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

---

My question is whether there is any functionality that lets you remove downstream and/or upstream dependencies once they are defined.

I have a fairly big DAG where most of the tasks (and their dependencies) are generated dynamically. Once the tasks are created, I would like to re-arrange some of the dependencies and/or introduce some new tasks.

For example, assuming that the functionality implements the following logic

```
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_1')
t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_2')

t1 >> t2
```

I would like to then be able to add a new task, add it in between the two tasks, and then remove the old dependency between `t1` and `t2`. Is this possible?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

def function_that_creates_dags_dynamically():
    tasks = {
        't1': DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_1'),
        't2': DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_2'),

    }
    tasks['t1'] >> tasks['t2']
    return tasks

with DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    tasks = function_that_creates_dags_dynamically()

    t3 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_3')
    tasks[t1] >> t3
    t3 >> tasks[t2] 
   # Somehow remove tasks[t1] >> tasks[t2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can remove an existing dependency like so:

```py
t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t1")
t2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t2")
t3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t3")

t1 >> t2
t1 >> t3 >> t2

t1.downstream_task_ids.remove("t2")
```

This results in only the dependency `t1 >> t3 >> t2`:

[image]

Each task internally stores the dependencies in sets `upstream_task_ids` and `downstream_task_ids`, which you can manipulate. However, it feels like a workaround to me and I'd advise generating only the correct dependencies in the first place if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not too sure as to whether it answers my question. What you say, applies even when we add extra dependencies between tasks. What I am looking to do is to programmatically remove a task dependency after it's defined.

Comment: The type of change itself doesn't make a difference, Airflow will display the DAG as defined in your DAG file. If this doesn't answer, please clarify what you expect to happen with "removing t1 >> t2".

Comment: @BasHarenslak My question is how to actually remove (programmatically) a dependency between two tasks. Tasks `task_1` and `task_2` and their dependencies, are created dynamically. After these tasks are created, I want to drop a specific dependency such that `t1 >> t2` no longer holds

Comment: I'm not following. If you update your code from `t1 >> t2` to `t1 >> t2 >> t3`, then there's no more (direct) dependency between `t1` and `t2`. "Removing" would mean you just don't define the dependency in your code.

Comment: @BasHarenslak Exactly. The point here is that `t1 >> t2` dependency is created dynamically. Once it is created, I want to know if I can somehow delete it (let's say with a `del` operation). 

In other words, I am not looking into how NOT to define a dependecy. I want to remove it once it is created/defined

Comment: @BasHarenslak I have just updated my question to include a more concrete example